# ¿Como pausar automaticamente un audio en netbeans java?

Tags: java

Buen día, conozco muy poco acerca de programación, estoy haciendo un proyecto en netbeans en java con un Jframe, en donde por medio de un cuadro de lista se selecciona un concepto y de ahi se escucha un audio 
Todo marcha bien hasta que selecciono otro audio y se juntan los sonidos distorsionándose por completo
¿Hay alguna forma de pausar un audio al cambiar de opción?
Se los agradecería mucho
Este es mi codigo

```
   String ruta2 = "G://Proyecto//src//Sonidos e imagenes//Sonidos//Digestivo";
```

Esta es la ruta en donde estan ubicados los audios

```
   private void lstProcesosMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         

    String Archivo = ruta2 + "//" + lstProcesos.getSelectedValue() + ".wav";

    try{
        Clip sonido=AudioSystem.getClip();
        sonido.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(Archivo)));
        sonido.start();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(""+e);

    }

}
```

Comment: este código es java, no javascript (corrección hecha)

Comment: Oh, Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar el método [**stop()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#stop())

```
sonido.stop()
```

Debes detener el audio y reproducir nuevamente mediante `start()`

Comment: Muchas gracias, no lo habia pensado asi, lo intentare